# Transforming textarea to function to button

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a function that will read the text area and transform it into string and type it somewhere. I expect it to display the paragraph with id biljeske. but it doesnt show anything at all. i dont know where i failed in this code.
`<textarea name="notes" rows="10" cols="30" autofocus></textarea>`

```
<p Id="biljeske"></p>


function novaBiljeska()
{
var strNotes;
strNotes = notes.getText();
document.getElementById("biljeske").innerHTML = strNotes;
}


<input type="button" value="Show" onclick="novaBiljeska()" >
```

Comment: What's currently happening that you aren't expecting?

Comment: thanks for the help, i have to start somewhere. that -1 was very welcoming to this community :)

Comment: as @imjared was hinting, the -1 usually means there's something that needs to be improved in the question. The comment indicates that it is unclear what your expected output is. When you come across unexpected results and post here, it is _expected_ that you post your actual vs expected output. Also, please note the -1 could be from some random person that did not leave a comment.

Comment: Hey @misterbobek - it's great that your question includes a description of what you're trying to get to happen, but it would be very helpful if you could also describe what is currently happening too! That falls under the category of "Introduce the problem" on Stackoverflow's ["How do I ask a good question" guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - would def recommend following those guidelines to get more useful answers, and more upvotes (and fewer downvotes) :)

Comment: Also - from the code you included, it's not super clear where `notes` in `notes.getText()` is coming from. Did you define `notes` as a variable somewhere else?

Comment: The text comes from `notes.getText();` but you don't show us what `notes`  is or where it came from or the `getText()` function (if it is one you wrote).

Comment: i made name in textarea notes, isnt the syntax name.getText() for me to get text from textarea??

Comment: You say you gave a name attribute but it is not in the code you posted. Also, giving a name but getting it by id - think about that.

Comment: @takendarkk the textarea with name attribute is actually included in the question, just not in the main code block.

Comment: @erikamjoh That's why there is a qualifier "_in the code you posted_". Question text and question code are considered separate. OP either needs to give us the exact code that is being executed or risk getting downvoted and ignored.

Comment: @takendarkk got it, thanks for clarifying. I could see how the distinction might be unclear to a new user though.

Comment: @misterbobek I think you have some misconceptions about the syntax `name.getText()`. Here are the properties of `textarea` object: [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp). The proper way to get the text/value of a textarea is by first getting the textarea by id and then accessing the [`value` property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice you're using `getElementBy**Id**()` but the textarea has no ID attribute, it only has name attribute. So, you'll never get the textarea. Simply add an id="notes" attribute to  should fix it.

Comment: The only getById is `getElementById("biljeske")` and that id is defined right here `<p Id="biljeske"></p>`. We don't see any code where OP tries to get the textarea by id.

Comment: The existing `getElementById()` call appears to be accessing some other element, not the textarea, in order to display the value there. It looks like the question was edited to include a `<p Id="biljeske"></p>` (altho should note that it is best practice to use lowercase **id** not **Id**), so the current line of code that calls `getElementById()` should no longer be an issue.

Comment: @erikamjoh At least in Chrome the capital I in Id makes no difference - the js still functions correctly.

Comment: @takendarkk yup you're totally right, I do believe it's better practice to use lowercase id though (not sure if you saw I edited my comment moments after I posted it to clarify that it's best practice, not required).

Answer (score 0):

i found out, thought i cant use ID for textarea. sorry for all the mess ive made. im a beginner and i dont know much. thanks everoyone